# What is the Max Level in Atelier Rorona Plus?

Tags: atelier-rorona-plus

I'm on Assignment 12 going though Orthogalaxen with Esty and Cordelia and i believe Floor 15 because i just fought a second Dragon. after beating it i noticed that while "To Next LV" went down for Rorona, Esty's was on 0 and didn't change at all and both Rorona and Esty are on Level 50 (Cordelia is on 47).

now while the final assignment one of the optional goals is to have Rorona with an Adventure Level of 50 so one would expect this to be the max since in the original game after this the game ended, however i know that in the remake after the game there's an "Overtime" segment which features

> Rorona meeting Totori and Meruru who have apparently came from the future

but it wouldn't explain why Esty seems to have Level Capped.

So what is the Max Level for *Atelier Rorona Plus*? is it different between Rorona and other characters? (like Cordelia, Sterk or Astrid)